# PostgreSQL copy text type column to text[] array type column

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion

I have two columns, `material_size` (`text` type) and `material_size_temp` (`text[]` array type).

When I ran `UPDATE parts SET material_size_temp[0] = material_size;` I would get values like `[0:0]={".021 x 2.450"}` instead of `{".021 x 2.450"}`.

How do I clone the `text` type column to `text[]` array type column?

Comment: Do you want to replace the existing value in `material_size_temp` (the whole array) or just the first element? Or do you want to *prepend* the array with the text from `material_size`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Most rows have data (just a single measurement) and some no data. I was just trying to move the data in to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was close, unlike JavaScript and PHP it seems PostgreSQL array key numbers start with 1, not 0.

```
UPDATE parts SET material_size_temp[1] = material_size;
```